# How to avoid unwanted Ajax and JSON caching in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, caching, websocket, internet-explorer-10

I'm having a problem with our ASP.NET MVC4 web application:

Our web application is used for realtime data visualization of values and parameters of different industrial devices. When a typical monitoring page gets opened in a client's browser, the page itself is static at first. When the document has finished loading, the current values for the datapoints on this page get loaded via an ajax call from the database. The call returns JSON data that feeds the viewmodel, which is then used by Knockout.js to update the UI elements with the data.

After this initial loading of current data, any upcoming changes to any of the currently displayed datapoints are transmitted from the server to the page via the WebSocket protocol and are then put into the viewmodel, replacing the old values. The new data also gets immediately written to the database, so that an ajax call would always deliver the up-to-date values.

So far, everything works really stable and fast in all HTML5-capable browsers - except for Internet Explorer 10. I'd like to add: OF COURSE ;-)

The problem in detail:

1. When I open a specific page with some datapoints, it loads the page. The current values get correctly fetched from the DB with ajax. Then, new values arrive and they are shown correctly with the mechanisms described above. The values in the UI get updated.
2. Now I change to another page, wait for it to get loaded completely, and then I go back to the first page (it doesn't matter if I do this with the "Go Back" button or by clicking a link or entering the URL manually), the page does NOT display the current values, but the values that had been loaded initially in step one via ajax.

The confusing thing is: I verified that the database DOES contain the up-to-date values and not the values shown on the page, therefore they should have get loaded with the initial ajax call when returning to the first page. The annoying thing: they DO get loaded in Firefox, Chrome, and even IE9 etc - but not in IE10.

Is there some new caching mechanism in IE10? How can I resolve this issue? Besides that: as far as I can see, it looks like there's some kind of Ajax / JSON caching going on here, are there ways to definitely prohibit HTML and JSON caching completely / globally in my ASP.NET MVC4 project or IIS?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: do you use jquery for ajax calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery AJAX method allows you to turn caching off:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  data: 'foo',
  success: function(){
    alert('bar');
  },
  cache: false
});
```

If this does not solve you can use the querystring trick:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html"+'?ts=' + $.now(),
  ...
  cache: false
});
```

Anyway the `cache: false` will do the trick. If not maybe you are using an old jquery version and it is better to upgrade.